# QTimer не срабатывает

Tags: c++, qt

Доброго времени суток! Написал небольшой класс и в нем QTimer, но при вызове start() приложение входит в вечный цикл. С моей точки зрения, все норм, но видимо, что-то я не учел.

**myclass.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
class MyClass: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
 public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    void start();
    virtual ~MyClass();
public slots:
    void showMessage();
private:
    QTimer *timer;
};
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <iostream>
MyClass::MyClass(QObject *p): QObject(p)
{
 timer = new QTimer(this);
 QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyClass::showMessage);    
}
void MyClass::showMessage()
{
    timer->stop();
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
void MyClass::start()
{
    timer->start(1);
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    delete timer;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "myclass.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyClass my;
    my.start();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Вот это `a.exec()` запускает «вечный» цикл сообщений Qt, почитайте как это работает в справке — это лежит в основе любой Qt программы (любой программы с интерфейсом, если копать глубже)

Comment: @ixSci как работает exec() я понимаю, проблема в том, что timeout таймера не наступает.

Comment: Кстати говоря, нет необходимости делать `delete timer`, так как у него есть parent. И для разового срабатывания есть singleShot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не понимаю в чём вопрос. У меня этот код собирается и работает корректно. Если у Вас не выводится **"Hello World!"**, то это проблемы как я думаю именно с выводом (оно, скорее всего, выводит, просто Вы не видите куда). Можете попробовать создать `Widget` что бы было точно видно-заметно. Если вопрос в том, почему приложение не останавливается - а почему оно должно? Сам таймер останавливается, но цикл обработки событий продолжается. Можете попробовать дописать например `exit(0)` в ваш слот - тогда приложение завершится (с кодом 0).